# How to access the controller for a given component tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design

I have the following basic Angular project:

https://plnkr.co/edit/P0z8PAqxxtdZqiQXambX?p=preview

If I click the button: `Reset to: [ New York, Chicago, Los Angeles ]` it changes the states on the select component properly.

Then, I want to change the states on the same select component in the same way by clicking the button: `Reset States to list above`.

I would like to know how to access the controller for a given component tag?, in this case for the tag: `material-app` on the `index.html` file so I can perform that change?

```
<material-app>Loading...</material-app>
```

I think I need to add something inside the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.button_reset').click(function(){
        var arr_states = $('.textarea_states').val().split('\n').filter(function(elem){ return elem.trim() != ''; });
        alert('How to set this?: ' + arr_states);
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think a good start point is to create a new component where encapsulates the sections that comes after `<material-app>Loading...</material-app>` tag, Then you may have two options: 1) Use an `@Output`  parameter adding an `EventEmiter` into the component where action is originated and bind it to `material-app` component. (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)    2)  Inject a service to communicate both components.

Comment: I was thinking in somethink like the function: `getScope` in the source code of: https://zeuscronos.github.io/angular-material-multiple-components/datepicker.html

Comment: That code that you are looking at is for angularjs which is a total different approach.  My suggestion is take a look at the heroes tutorial from angular official documentation https://angular.io/tutorial.  Cheers

Comment: The JavaScript code you wrote looks a lot like JQuery!

Comment: Stop thinking in Jquery

Comment: but is it possible to achieve this from out of the scope using javascript?